# should I publish an app If I need to test phonegapp In app purchasement?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I need to test phonegap in app purchase plugin.

on the itunes connenct site, I am not sure should I select  manage your application >> add new app button for testing in app purchasement.

I dont have a purpose of publising app or informing app launching date. I only need to test 
In app purchasement. 
what should I do let apple know I only need to test my developing app for only in app purchasement? 
or is there something I miss? 
can I test in app purchasement without publishing to itunesconnect? how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the iTunes Connect for testing the in-app purchase.
But you don't need to transfer your binary file to iTunes Connect for testing In-App purchase.

This is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases), please refer it.

Comment: that means... should I provide all informations except my app file? should I include launch date and app images , support url etc?

Comment: @SehoLee: sure you want to fill all datas, excluding the app file

Comment: @SehoLee: I have added a link, please refer that tutorial :)